# where to type the password for printing over internet and can not install the driver on 10.10

Tags: macos, printing

My company has a network printer **KONICA MINOLTA C353**, I have added it on my Mac.

I know there is still a password needed to fill in, but I can't find where to input it.

What a bad luck is that I can install the latest driver on osx 10.10 (you can see the two disks are gray, you can install on it)

[image]

[image]

[image: inline]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this window on my end so I can't say for sure... But.. I would imagine it's under the "Advanced" button next to your printer's IP address.

Konica Minolta printers call this feature "Account tracking", where you enter a password that is designated to you/your department so that they can track usage.  I would click the Advanced button and look for a password field or mention of Account Track.

If that doesn't work, and assuming you have the proper drivers loaded, I would try clicking the "Printer..." button in the bottom left of the dialogue.  This should open a standard OS X print dialogue (rather than the Adobe one in your screenshot) that should have an option in the dropdown menu for Security.  Under that option you should have an Account Track field.  Again, all of this is assuming you have the proper Konica driver installed.  The below example doesn't have the field I'm referring to but if it did, this is where it would appear.

[image]